# How do I get the first object, from each group of objects in core data

Tags: swift, core-data

This is my sample data table which is called "Conversations":

| ID | ConsumerID | CreationDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | aaa | 23/8/2000 |
| 2 | aaa | 21/8/2000 |
| 3 | aaa | 10/7/2000 |
| 4 | bbb | 30/8/2000 |
| 5 | bbb | 1/7/2000 |
| 6 | bbb | 22/7/2000 |

I'm using NSFetchRequest to get the newest conversation, for each consumerID, but I can't find anything similar online.

This is my expected response:

| ID | ConsumerID | CreationDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | aaa | 23/8/2000 |
| 4 | bbb | 30/8/2000 |

Actually i'm trying to get the conversations objects that match that criteria. The creation date could not have duplications so there is no need to handle such cases.

Can anyone help me with that please?

Comment: Use [sort descriptor](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsfetchrequest/1506262-sortdescriptors) for your fetch request and set [fetch limit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsfetchrequest/1506622-fetchlimit) to 1.

Comment: Using fetchLimit = 1 will give me only one result. How do I make sure the fetchLimit is for each group?

Comment: Ah, I missed that. There is a property for grouping, [propertiesToGroupBy](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsfetchrequest/1506191-propertiestogroupby) that might work here but note that this is to used with a dictionary and not an entity as return value for the request

Comment: Yes, I seen it but as you mentioned, it doesn't give me what I actually need.

Comment: If you are certain there are no duplicate creationDates, you can do a first fetch to get max(creationDate) grouped by consumerID (using `propertiesToGroupBy` as @JoakimDanielson says).  That will give you a collection of creationDates.  Then do a second fetch to get the objects with those creationDates.